# How to store UIWebView cache in iOS so that it does not blink when a page opens

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, caching, uiwebview

I have a simple app loading a site optimized for the iPhone in a `UIWebView`.
But when the `webview` loads some pages blink on click.
i think its a cache problem. i am using some variables to store last pages value.
Please suggest some good ideas.
Thanks

Here is the code I am using

```
NSString *strPassword1=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"password"];
NSString *strUsername1=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userName"];
if (strUsername1.length!=0&&strPassword1.length!=0)
{


    NSString* userId1   = strUsername1; //here just replace that string to the username
    NSString* password1 =   strPassword1;//here just replace that string to the password


    if(userId1 != nil && password1 != nil )
    {

        NSString*  jScriptString1 = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('username').value='%@'",userId1];
        //username is the id for username field in Login form

        NSString*  jScriptString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('password').value='%@'",password1];
        //here password is the id for password field in Login Form
        //Now Call The Javascript for entring these Credential in login Form
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString1];

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString2];
        //Further if you want to submit login Form Automatically the you may use below line

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.forms[0].submit();"];


        NSString *strTemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", webView.request.URL];
        if ([strTemp isEqualToString:@"http://test.xyz.com/"])
            _webView.hidden=NO;

    }
}
else
{

    if(self.userName.length!=0&&self.password.length!=0)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.xyz.com/login?ios_id=%@",appKey]];

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)

        {
           // NSLog(@"%@", data);
        }];
    }


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.userName] forKey:@"userName"];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.password] forKey:@"password"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slick solution is to change UIWebViews as loads occur.  Setup properties for your webView and a new "offscreen" web view where the loads will occur...

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;  // assume you have this 
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *offscreenWebView;
```

Initialize the offscreen web view to have the same frame and delegate as the initial web view...

```
self.offscreenWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webView.frame];
self.offscreenWebView.delegate = self;
```

Implement the delegate.  When the delegate asks to start a load, answer NO and instead start the load in the offscreen web view...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // It's advisable to present some "busy" UI here, like an activity indicator
    [self.offscreenWebView loadRequest:request];
    return NO;
}
```

When the load is finished, swap the onscreen and offscreen web views...

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    // remove the busy UI here

    if (webView == self.offscreenWebView) {
        // swap them on the parent
        [self.view addSubview:self.offscreenWebView];
        [self.webView removeFromSuperview];

        // swap our pointers to them
        UIWebView *temp = self.offscreenWebView;
        self.offscreenWebView = self.webView;
        self.webView = temp;
    }
}
```